# why bcc emails sent via php mail are not hidden

Tags: php, email, bcc

i am trying to send emails via Bcc and i was expecting that they were hidden but it seems not. Maybe my code is not correct?

```
// grab all emails from txt file
$myfile = fopen("database-email.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$allEmails = fread($myfile,filesize("database-email.txt"));
fclose($myfile);

$afzender = "noreply@wisselslag.nl";

$to = 'pj.maessen41@live.nl';

$subject = 'Nieuwsbrief de Wisselslag';

$headers = "From: " . $afzender . "\r\n";   
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: " . $allEmails  . "\r\n";

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
  echo 'Bericht is verstuurd!';
} else {
  echo 'There was a problem sending the email.';
}
```

So i have a `database-email.txt` file in which all the emails are stored, comma seperated from each other like this:

```
joey.tims@gmail.com,
j.maessen@online.nl,
john.doe@live.nl,
diana.johnson@hotmail.com,
```

When sending to my gmail account, i can see this:

[image]

How is this possible that i can see to where the email also is sent to?

Comment: Does `$afzender` have a value?

Comment: `$afzender = "noreply@wisselslag.nl;`

Comment: Recipients of emails can always see the "To" and "CC" list. Only the "BCC" list is hidden

Comment: yes the Bcc should be hidden. But i can see the whole bcc list

Comment: Your issue appears to be that the newlines in your file cause any address after the first to be placed in the email body. Simply remove the newlines

Comment: Ah, so Jack Maessen shouldn't be seeing the whole bcc list!

Comment: I agree, the newlines where the problem. it works now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The email list should not have new line character.

Make it one line:

```
$allEmails = str_replace(array("\n","\r"), '', $allEmails);

// joey.tims@gmail.com, j.maessen@online.nl, john.doe@live.nl, diana.johnson@hotmail.com
```

Comment: That really makes sense! Awesome solution. I understand now what i did wrong. Works great now. Thanks @Ben

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, any list of recipients should not contain newline characters.

I'd change the format of your file to a single line

```
joey.tims@gmail.com,j.maessen@online.nl,john.doe@live.nl,diana.johnson@hotmail.com
```

I'd also use `file_get_contents()` instead of `fopen` / `fread`.

---

Alternately, store your email addresses on each line, without commas, eg

```
joey.tims@gmail.com
j.maessen@online.nl
john.doe@live.nl
diana.johnson@hotmail.com
```

and use [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/function.file.php) and `implode()`

```
$allEmails = implode(',' file(__DIR__ . '/database-email.txt',
        FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
```